# CSS: Rev Slider slideshow displaced in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

[This page](http://freightplus.com/beta/) has a Revolution Slider that looks fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

In Microsoft Edge the slider is pushed down below the end of the sidebar `#boxes`.

[image]

Can you see how we push this back up to work like in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the very end of your theme / child theme functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'ava_auto_resize');
function ava_auto_resize(){
?>
<script>
(function($){   
    var int = window.setInterval(function(){
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }, 2000);

    $(window).load(function () {    
        setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(int);
        }, 3000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
```